# Disabling warning variable might not have been initialized?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lint

I have 2 variables, and according to some case in an if else I either use the code with the first variable **variable1** or else the code with the second one **variable2**.

**Both of the variables are declared as final** and I only assign them at the condition and I use different statements on them.

Any idea on how I could disable the android warning for both of these statements ?

Is there any other way to do this without using **asserts** or **checking if the variable has the value null** after I initialize it in the if or else ?

I am very certain that my code does work and there is no way I use a variable which is not initialized, I would prefer a way to disable only the warnings for these statements and not for the whole project.

Which would be the best way to implement this ?

```
private static class foo {

private final objectwhatever variable1;
private final objectwhatever variable2;

public foo(){

   if ( condition 1)
   {
          variable1 = new objectwhatever();
          statements in variable1
   } 

  else ( condition 2)
  {
          variable2 = new objectwhatever();
          statements in variable2
  } 

}
}
```

Comment: If the type of both the variables are same then why are you creating two different variables in the first place? I don't understand the use case here.

Comment: You haven't provided accurate (or even valid) code. In particular, you probably don't have a "default" else condition.

Comment: Why don't you use only one variable of type 'objectwhatever' and initialize it in your constructor?

Comment: Long story short, it is the same class. Once it is imported through android native, one as an external library from me. I need the second one when the android native does not work for api level above then or equal to 18. Trust me this information is enough for the answer that I do want. The class although it is the same, it is renamed so they do not conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `final` variable must be assigned once in the constructor or out of it. This is a Java rule, you cannot disable the error warning. But, if you remove `final`, the error will disappear.

For some reason, you may want to disable all Android lints, i.e. by using `@SuppressWarnings("ALL")` to your class or method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
private static class foo {

    private objectwhatever variable1;
    private objectwhatever variable2;
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: added a null assignment in each case to the other variable, had forgotten that every final variable should have been assigned once atleast. Your answer returned my memory, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you must suppress it, use `@SuppressWarnings("InstanceVariableMayNotBeInitialized")`, suppressing "ALL" is kind-of overkill.

Comment: How do I know what the warning is called in code, i.e. that InstanceVariableMayNotBeInitialized is what I should put in between ""?